# Express - Get response from one url to another

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a post methon that calculate some thing and return it with the `res.json` method. 
The code look something like this:

```
app.post("/calc", function (req, res) {
    res.json({result: 100});
});
```

I want to get that JSON from another post method, like that:

```
app.post("/useCalc", function (req, res) {
    let json = // Call "/calc" somehow...
    console.log(json) // print {result: 100}
    res.end();
});
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Just make a common function that both of your routes can call.  This is just a plain Javascript thing - nothing uniquely related to being in routes.

Answer (score 0):

One workable approach is using a 307, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect#99966.

Another way I would suggest is to create a common method to handle them two.